# Regex: выберите все файлы, содержащие пробелы между тегами

Tags: регулярные-выражения, windows, notepad++

Здравствуйте. У меня этот тип тегов:

```
</ Р>
```

СОДЕРЖАНИЕ .....

```
<! - * * * * * ВСЕ ЛЮБИТ * * * * * ->
```

а также

```
</ Р>
```

```
<!- * * * * * ВСЕ ЛЮБИТ * * * * * ->
```

Я хочу выбрать все файлы, которые содержат пробелы между `</ p>` и `<!-` теги (второй пример выше)

Answer (score 1):

вы должны использовать эту формулу

```
</p>\s+<!--
```